# Store class type as map value and initialize new class based on map key

Tags: c++, class, types

I want to write a function that returns a new class instance based on a static mapping from Enum to class type.

```
Base* getBase(Enum e) {
    static const map<Enum, class type???> base_map = {
        { EnumA, Derived1 }, // Derived1,2,3 are subclasses of Base
        { EnumB, Derived2 },
        { EnumC, Derived3 },
    };
    return new base_map[e];
}
```

Is it possible to do this in C++? If so, what type should map's value have?
I guess I could use a long `if-else` to achieve the same effect, but using a map seems more cleaner.

Comment: I would just go with a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a factory function - something along these lines:

```
Base* getBase(Enum e) {
    typedef std::function<Base*()> maker_t;
    static const map<Enum, maker_t> base_map = {
        { EnumA, [] { return new Derived1; } },
        { EnumB, [] { return new Derived2; } },
        { EnumC, [] { return new Derived3; } }
    };
    return base_map[e]();
}
```